# Mapping values of a matrix to another matrix

Tags: matlab, dictionary, matrix, dimensions

I have two matrices with the following dimensions:

```
matrix_1 --> 143810x2

matrix_2 --> 394x365
```

Regarding `matrix_1`, it will eventually evaluate to a matrix of dimension `143810x1`.

Since `394x365 = 143810x1`, what I want to do is map the values in `matrix_1` to `matrix_2` with having the dimension in `matrix_2`.

How can I do that in `matlab`?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen the [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) function?

Comment: It's hard to understand how you would like to "map" them.

Answer (score 1):

[Reshape](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) lets you rearrange the data in an array by changing the dimensions. The input and output must have the same number of elements so you can do one column of `matrix_1` at a time.

```
matrix_2_col_1 = reshape(matrix_1(:,1), size(matrix_2));
matrix_2_col_2 = reshape(matrix_1(:,2), size(matrix_2));
```

Comment: The reason that I want it to be as the same dimension as `matrix_2` is that I need to perform an `8x8 neighbourhood` operation on the matrix. Does that make sense? Thanks